# Cannot get blob

Tags: java, file, http, url, blob

I want to convert a blob to a mp3-audiFile from my own website so i made this testclass. I keep on getting this message, and when i remove 'blob:' from the link, i get a FileNotFoundException. How can I solve this? I cannot really find anything on the internet that gives a sollution.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    class AudioConverter {

        public static File convertBlobToAudio(String blobLink, String title) throws IOException {

            URL url = new URL(blobLink);

            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

            File audioFile = File.createTempFile(title, ".mp3");

            Files.copy(inputStream, audioFile.toPath());

            return audioFile;

        }

        public static File getAndOrCreateDirectory(String username) {

            String directory = "C:\\Users\\prody\\IdeaProjects\\testje3\\src\\instrumentals";

            File[] fileList = new File(directory).listFiles();

            for (File file: fileList) {
                if (file.getName().equals(username)) {
                    return file;
                }
            }

            File newDirectory = new File(directory, username);

            if (newDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                return newDirectory;
            }

            return null;

        }

        public static boolean addAudioToDirectory(File audioFile, File directory) {

            return audioFile.renameTo(directory);

        }

    }

    File audio = AudioConverter.convertBlobToAudio("http://localhost:8080/cb4f0a31-57ef-407a-b56a-0d9eebf1a82f", "title");
    System.out.println(audio);

    File directory = AudioConverter.getAndOrCreateDirectory("prodByPieter");
    System.out.println(directory);

    boolean succes = AudioConverter.addAudioToDirectory(audio, directory);
    System.out.println(succes);
}
```

}

This is the message that i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: blob
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:682)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:570)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:517)
at Main$1AudioConverter.convertBlobToAudio(Main.java:18)
at Main.main(Main.java:60)
```